# Pyinstaller [3060] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

After covering my .py file to .exe on Windows 10 64bit using Pyinstaller, i sent the .exe file to computer which works on Windows 7 32bit. The .exe file perfectly works on my Windows 10 64bit and Windows7 64bit computers.
Does anybody have any idea what can i do with it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKErX.jpg)

Comment: You cannot run 64bit programs on 32bit machines, just the other way around.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer so, i need to cover my program to .exe on 32bit computer?

Comment: Yes and the oldest OS version you want to run the program on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to install Service Pack 1 on that Win7 32bit computer. By the way, i covered .py to .exe ob 32bit computer.

Comment: What did you do after you installed SP1? Did you just run it again and it worked?

Comment: @PianoPianist yes